# Synchronized zooming of two TChart components

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, teechart

I'm using two TChart components and would like to do synchronized zooming for them. I found that TChart has ZoomRect procedure for zooming into a desired rectangle on the chart but I haven't found any way to read the coordinates of this zoom rectangle from another chart.

Here's some pseudo code for extra clarification:

```
MainChart.OnZoom := HandleZooming;

...

procedure HandleZooming(Sender: TObject);
var
  zoomRectangle: TRect;
begin
  zoomRectangle := MainChart.?????;
  SecondaryChart.ZoomRect(zoomRectangle);
end;
```

I'm using Delphi XE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
zoomRectangle := Rect(
  MainChart.Zoom.X0, 
  MainChart.Zoom.Y0, 
  MainChart.Zoom.X1,
  MainChart.Zoom.Y1
);
```

Comment: Damn, can't believe I missed that!